# Extracting relative links from a web page in proper format using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I have parsed the outlinks of a web page which I am going to parse again using Jsoup. But the problem is that, the links are of the form: `../../../pincode/india/andaman-and-nicobar- islands/`. In this form I cannot parse them. So I have converted to absolute url using `link.attr("abs:href")` with the help of other post of stackoverflow.

Url of the first web page that I have parsed is: `http://www.mapsofindia.com/pincode/india/`. And the absolute URls that I have got after parsing is of the form `http://www.mapsofindia.com/../pincode/india/andaman-and-nicobar-islands/`. But I cannot parse them further using Jsoup. So when I am executing the following statement:

`Jsoup.parse("http://www.mapsofindia.com/../pincode/india/andaman-and-nicobar-islands/");`

It is giving HTTP 400 error i.e. bad request. So I think there is some problem with the Urls. So can anyone please help me to solve the above problem to get the urls in proper manner so that I can parse them further. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

please test these two things:

1. try using `link.absUrl("href")` instead of `link.attr("abs:href")`
2. Check the base uri (calling `baseUri()` on your element or document)

Btw. you better use `connect()` Method for this thing:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://<your url here>").get();
```